# Refresh User Claims without logout then login

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

**How things are set up:**

i have a **front end portal** and the I**dentity Server** :

• Front End portal (angular) uses oidc client for authentication

• When a user access the front end portal he gets redirected to the Identity Server to login

• After a successful authentication, i set up the claims in the identity server and the user gets redirected to the front end portal with an id_token and an access_token

• I can access the claims using the user of the oidc client (user.profile)

**Issue / Question:**

**If i update the user's first name for example, how can update the user claims instantly so the end user can see his changes immediately? is logging out then logging in obligatory in this case or is there anyway i can update the claims?**

• **OIDC configuration**:

```
OIDC_SETTINGS: UserManagerSettings = {
        authority: environment.IdentityServer,
        client_id: 'client_id',
        redirect_uri: environment.portal + '/callback',
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        scope: 'openid profile ',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.portal,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        silent_redirect_uri: environment.portal + '/refresh',
        includeIdTokenInSilentRenew: true
    };
```

• In the **Identity server** i set the claims after the log in is successful like this and using the **GetUserClaims** method

```
 await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id.ToString(), user.FullName, props, (await _identityManager.GetUserClaims(user)).ToArray());
```

• Example from the **GetUserClaims** method

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UserName));
```

and the 'email' claim type should be in the UserClaims array of the 'profile' identity resource

I hope this helps! Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Without building some custom notification mechanism, you will have to wait for users to logout/login.